Azure functions app .net zip deployment versioning
I'm looking for some standard way to track which version of my .net app (assembly version?) is deployed in my azure functions app.
The deployment method is ZIP and the .NET in-process model is used.
I'm looking for some place on the Azure Portal or some way within Azure CLI to query which version of my .NET code is currently deployed in a particular functions app resource (and the way to specify the version in the app).

You could set your version during build (dotnet build /p:Version=1.2.3) and then add an endpoint to your app that reads the current assembly version and returns it.

Thanks for the insight @Good Night Nerd Pride.

Use the below code to check the Assembly Version of the function app:

 Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

Code Snippet:
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
 
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
        : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage+" and version "+version);
}


Deploy the function to Azure and browse the function URL to check the version in the response.

Response:

You can set the required Assembly version in the application before publishing to Azure.

Right click on the Project=> Select Properties=>Package=>Change the Package version to preferred version.



After updating the setting, assembly version will be added in the version tag in .csproj file:

 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
   <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
   <Version>1.2.3</Version>
 </PropertyGroup>

